# Manage ads inside a Single Page Application

Tags: single-page-application, ads, adsense, google-dfp

I m developing a Single Page Application (SPA). So, I use to refresh the page's HTML's content dynamically using Ajax requests.

I'd like to register to the DoubleClick for Publishers program, but I m wondering if my SPA is able to integrate advertising due to its dynamic content loaded without refreshing the page.

I saw this link: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726

So I assume it's ok. But I'd like to be certain before starting using DFP. Could someone confirm please?

Then, sometimes I m using external html pages that I still load using Ajax. Should I consider writing the advertising banners JavaScript inside these external views, or directly inside the master page of my app?

Last question: How can I manage users having an adblocker software installed? Am I allowed to detect the presence of an adblocker software using JavaScript and then execute some specific code for this kind of users?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working in a SPA and working with DFP successfully. Here is my feedback to your questions:

> So I assume it's ok. But I'd like to be certain before starting using
>   DFP. Could someone confirm please?

- Yes, you can refresh the banners using the method you are refering in the link you shared

> Then, sometimes I m using external html pages that I still load using
>   Ajax. Should I consider writing the advertising banners JavaScript
>   inside these external views, or directly inside the master page of my
>   app?

- To load them externally will bring you to lower performance results. You can control everything from the main page and you will have better results.

> Last question: How can I manage users having an adblocker software
>   installed? Am I allowed to detect the presence of an adblocker
>   software using JavaScript and then execute some specific code for this
>   kind of users?

- This is something I have not started to work on it but you can detect (like [forbes.com](http://www.forbes.com) is doing on it website) and there are also projects on dealing with [this](https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock).